# WordPress Scheduler Email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

Im not very good with WordPress php codings and multiple loops please some help out.

I am trying to create a API function call scheduler mailing. what it do is to check the posts table to get woocommerce ordered post. getting the post_modified meta where post_status is 'wc-completed' and base on the post_modified date the function will sent an email out to user after 5 day from the post_modified date.

```
public function schedulerMail(){
        global $wpdb;

        $s= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status like 'wc-completed'");
        for($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++){
            $post_data = array (
            'ID' => $s[$i]->ID,
            'post_modified' =>$s{$i}->post_modified,        
            );
            return array ("post"=>$post_data);
        }

    }
```

i have come up with this code and it did show the correct data for $s.

```
{
0: [
{
ID: "99",
post_modified: "2015-09-02 07:58:14"
},
{
ID: "100",
post_modified: "2015-09-04 02:59:27"
},
{
ID: "101",
post_modified: "2015-09-09 07:36:56"
}
],
status: "ok"
}
```

but when i return $post_data it only return me 1 line of data instead of 3

```
{
   status: "ok",
   post: {
      ID: "99",
      post_modified: "2015-09-02 07:58:14"
         }
}
```

i don know how to explain it but i want to do a date check base on these date and if date has past exactly 5 days, sent an email out.

Comment: As I can see, you are recreating / overwriting array every time in a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote return array in loop itself. Hence the program exit the loop in first ittiration.

```
public function schedulerMail(){
    global $wpdb;
    $s= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status like 'wc-completed'");
    $post_data = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++){
        /*$post_data = array (
        'ID' => $s[$i]->ID,
        'post_modified' =>$s{$i}->post_modified,
        );*/
        $post_data[$i]['ID'] = $s[$i]->ID;
        $post_data[$i]['post_modified'] = $s{$i}->post_modified;           
    }
    return array ("post"=>$post_data);
}
```

What You Wanted:

```
public function schedulerMail(){
        global $wpdb;
        $s= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status like 'wc-completed' AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY) <= post_modified");
        for($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++){
            $post_data[$i]['ID'] = $s[$i]->ID;
            //$this->mailout($post_data[$i]['ID']);

        }
        return array("ID"=> $post_data);
    }
```

Comment: I see THANKS very much it works now. OK for now i get each of my post and date right i want to check these date if more <5 days sent and email whr should i start to insert the code?

Comment: I think, you want post which are less then 5 days. In this case, add where clause for Post_Modified field like: where post_modified <= date

Comment: erm i mean for example now we call this schedulermail() and we know it give us this result {
status: "ok",
post: [
{
ID: "99",
post_modified: "2015-09-02 07:58:14"
},
{
ID: "100",
post_modified: "2015-09-04 02:59:27"
},
{
ID: "101",
post_modified: "2015-09-09 07:36:56"
}
]
}  so for each result if current date is 5 days after each the given result it will get the post ID and sent out a mail with datas from the ID.

Comment: Instead of checking date of each post, i would suggest that you apply where clause in SQL. this will make sure that all the data are less then 5 days only like '$s= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID,post_modified FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status like 'wc-completed'  and  post_modified <= 2015-09-09 07:36:56     ");'

Answer (score 0):

solved thanks to Ankur140290

```
public function schedulerMail(){
        global $wpdb;
        $s= $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_status like 'wc-completed' AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 10 DAY) <= post_modified");
        for($i = 0; $i < count($s); $i++){
            $post_data[$i]['ID'] = $s[$i]->ID;
            //$this->mailout($post_data[$i]['ID']);

        }
        return array("ID"=> $post_data);
    }
```